# SPARQL query that returns prefixed names instead of IRIs

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

Let's say I have these triples:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/>.
#rdf types
:john a :Person.
:liz a :Person.
:robert a :Person.
:dan a :Person.
```

I have to return all the subjects of these triples, so I do:

```
SELECT ?x
FROM <http://localhost:3030/Exercice3/data/>
WHERE {
    ?x ?y ?z
}
```

I get as I wanted:

```
<http://example.org/john>
<http://example.org/liz>
<http://example.org/robert>
<http://example.org/dan>
```

But now I have to return the local names of the subjects, that is to say:

```
:john
:liz
:robert
:dan
```

**How can I query the prefixed name before it is concatenated to an IRI ?**

I've tried on the string level but I think there's a more serious way to achieve it:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>

SELECT ?str
FROM <http://localhost:3030/Exercice3/data/>
WHERE {
    ?x ?y ?z
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?x),STR(:),STR(':')) AS ?str)
}
```

This is what I get so far:
(I am not expected to return strings)

```
":john"
":liz"
":robert"
":dan"
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Help you with what? You got what you needed, didn't you?

Comment: No, there is no quotemarks in the solution I should be returning. Because I guess they're not expecting strings as result.

Comment: This is related to the serialization of the query results. If you use [CSV serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-csv-tsv/), then Jena puts literals in quotes only if they contains commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is not possible using SPARQL alone.

A SPARQL SELECT query result contains three kinds of values: IRIs, literals, and blank nodes. The query in your question is about the closest you can get to returning strings that look like prefixed names as query results. In SPARQL terms, the values you get back are actually literals, and the double quotes are mandatory around literals. So there is no way to do this *without* having double quotes around each value.

A prefixed name is not a separate thing from an IRI: it is just a different way of *writing down* an IRI. What this means that it can not be controlled by the SPARQL query, which just returns the results in abstract form, but is controlled by whatever processor/formatter is used to format/convert/write the results.

I don't know how this works specifically in Jena (I'm a Sesame man myself) but generally, a SPARQL engine returns a query result in some internal representation - e.g. Java objects. How that data is then rendered depends on what you do with the result. For example, you might write it to a XML file using SPARQL XML Result Format, or you might loop over it and print the output to STDOUT as text. The point is: whether any IRI in your result is rendered/displayed as a prefixed name is determined by how you process the result, *not* by the query itself.